# Weblogic - FilterChainImpl IndexOutOfBoundsException on Struts2

Tags: java, struts, servlet-filters, struts-1, weblogic11g

we have recently upgraded to weblogic and started getting this error. While on Oracle IAS, there was nothing erroneous and the code hasn't changed a bit. but now, while the execution is in one of my filters, i got this error. I found out that it maybe a bug on the weblogic server but i couldn't find any solutions or workarounds. does anybody know why is this happening?

thanks in advance.

here's the log of the error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
    at java.util.LinkedList.entry(LinkedList.java:365)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:315)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:55)
    at tr.com.innova.tmh.web.surecLog.filter.OHMLoggerFilter.doFilter(OHMLoggerFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at tr.com.innova.common.web.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:176)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at tr.com.innova.tmh.web.utils.filters.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:16)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:527)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at tr.com.innova.tmh.web.popup.actions.ModalPopupAction.setFieldsAndRedirect(ModalPopupAction.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
    at tr.com.innova.tmh.web.utils.actions.TMHDispatchAction.execute(TMHDispatchAction.java:224)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at tr.com.innova.tmh.web.ss.filters.WebSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebSecurityFilter.java:97)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at tr.com.innova.tmh.web.ss.filters.WebLoginFilter.doFilter(WebLoginFilter.java:257)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at tr.com.innova.tmh.web.surecLog.filter.OHMLoggerFilter.doFilter(OHMLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at tr.com.innova.common.web.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:176)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at tr.com.innova.tmh.web.utils.filters.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:16)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: You should post at least `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access index 6 in a `LinkedList` whose size is already 6. List collection indexes start with 0, so if you want to access last item in the a `List`, `List#get(List#size()-1)` can be used. `5` is last index in your case.

As you say that exception is in weblogic. The list may be populated with server information. It may be a header entry which is added and it does not exists in web logic, so your code may has dependency to Oracle IAS.

Possible candidates are

- XSSFilter.java:16
- SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:176
- OHMLoggerFilter.java:75
- WebLoginFilter.java:257
- WebSecurityFilter.java:97
- TMHDispatchAction.java:224
- ModalPopupAction.java:32
- OHMLoggerFilter.java:81

**See also**

[List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

[Java Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

[Servlet Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)